# MVC 5 post JSON from an external site and return view with data

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 sites (same domain), using 2 separate web applications. I want to be able to to have links from one site to another. The link would send a large set of data to the other application, so I need to use POST, so that the other app can use and process this data.

So the idea is to use an AJAX call on domain.com/site1 and POST data that'll launch a view on domain.com/site2 that'll have access to said data via JavaScript.

I thought I'd be able to post the data to a controller and return a razor view with said data.

Something like this (though I know this doens't work because Controller != ApiController):

```
public class Site2Controller : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index([FromBody]Dictionary<string, dynamic> postedData)
    {
        var model = new Site2DataModel();
        model.someParam = postedData.someParam;

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Then in my view (let me know if this is dumb):

```
@model Site2.Site2DataModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Site2View.cshtml";
}

<form class="dataForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="someParam" value="@Model.someParam"/>
</form>
```

And in my JS, something like:

```
var viewData: any = $('.dataForm').serializeArray().reduce(function (obj, item) {
    obj[item.name] = item.value;
    return obj;
}, {});

var viewModel = viewData.someParam;
//...
```

Again, I know this doesn't work, and the reasons are obvious, but I don't know of any better way to handle this situation. Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like you want to post data to site2 from site1. However this requirement could be refined to other architecture/solutions like web service or API calls. Think through and cut your requirements to a simplest one you'll have the answer. And don't use iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will work too but I haven't tried it so I don't really know if you can return a ActionResult/View from a different project.

As for a work around what I do is instead of returning an ActionResult/View I'm returning a JsonResult/JSON and then call it through an ajax in the other project.

Project 1 you have.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Proj1Action(YourModelHere somedata)
{
    //some data modification here
    ...
    SomeModel modifiedModelData = new SomeModel
    {
         name = "testname"
    }
    return JSON(modifiedModelData);
}
```

And then do an ajax in Project 2:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://Project1/Project1Controller/Proj1Action",
        data: {somedata: dataYouWantToPass},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
             //result is the modifiedModelData that you got from Proj1Action
             console.log(result.name); 
        },
        error: function(xhr){
             console.log(xhr);
        }
    })
</script>
```